# Is it possible to install Windows Updates on multiple, remote servers through Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am a network admin with very little experience coding or using Powershell. About once a month I have to check for and install Windows updates on about 25 servers. I've played around with Powershell in hopes of handling this task in a more automated fashion but get hung up getting the servers to actually install the updates after checking. I apologize for posting such a noob question, but can anyone let me know if this is possible and if so, show me the ways of your dark arts?

Comment: Use WSUS. It's free and it's made for.  ;-)

Comment: Well, It is possible. See [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=WindowsUpdate) , there is PSWindowsUpdate module that can help you. If you want make on your own, you can read those modules.

Answer (score 0):

WSUS will require you to install the components and setup the profiles etc.  If you have a large number of servers on a single network, that is your best bet for delivering the content.

If you just want to be able to schedule and run the updates on specific remote hosts, there is a ton of stuff already available that will do this and you just need to come up with your implementation of scheduling the updates for what hosts.  I did this exact thing for a prior employer for 10k plus servers world wide using a web app for the owners to schedule the updates and then back end workflow to perform the approval requests, installs, logging, etc..

PowerShell Gallery is a good start.  Here is a [post that walks you through using PSWindowsUpdate](https://4sysops.com/archives/install-windows-updates-remotely-with-the-powershell/).